# Filter with Where and Order with Orderby in one line

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to pass an array, which contains all Apprentices, ordered by specialization, starting year and name.

```
$apprentices = Apprentice::orderBy('specialization', 'asc')->orderBy('startYear', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

This works perfectly fine, but now I only want to return the Datasets from the Apprentices, which started 4 years or less ago.
I Tried this:

```
        $apprentices = Apprentice::orderBy('specialization', 'asc')->orderBy('startYear', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get()->where('startYear' <= date("Y") - 4);
```

but this doesn't return anything.

Is it just a minor syntax error or is my idea from the ground up wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting `->get()` at the end?

Comment: @GluePear I added an additional `->get()` to the end but it threw the Error `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Comment: I meant moving `get` from where it is now to the end, not adding an additional one.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad. I tried it and it threw the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `apprentices` where `1` is null order by `specialization` asc, `startYear` asc, `name` asc)` What I don't get about it is, that in the where clause it only gets a 1, even tho I made a comparison.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause is incorrectly formed, and you need to move `get` to the end:

```
$apprentices = Apprentice::orderBy('specialization', 'asc')->orderBy('startYear', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->where('startYear', '<=', date("Y") - 4)->get();
```

See the manual for [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Comment: technically it would be `>=` but thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$apprentices = Apprentice::whereYear('startYear', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(4))->orderBy('specialization', 'asc')->orderBy('startYear', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything